# How to Autofill google username/email address into the column B when the column A is edited?

Tags: autofill

In google sheet, How to Autofill google username/email address(or even full name) of the person last edited column A into the next column, which is column B?

Can anyone share this script based on this example? Assuming a few people are allowed to edit A2 & C3. So I want to know who they are on B2 & D3
Been checking online, many asked the same questions but I unable to find workable & understandable solution.
I can create the list of the full name/email address of people allowed to edit that particular cell if this would help.

Basically I wanna ensure the correct person name is displayed cause if I use dropdown menu to ask editor to select, there is a possibility someone may choose the wrong name

Nothing work so far.